Cannot Work With Mosaico After Moving Site
I recently moved a WordPress CiviCRM install to Drupal 9.  Overall it is working well.  The biggest concern I have right now is that I cannot get Mosaico to work again.
I have tried multiple approaches to make it work. Most recently I found the Mosaico and Mailing Configuration Changes that should change the hard coded URLs in the database.   When I look at a mailing draft this is all that comes up.

If I hit the edit button I get this JavaScript error in the console.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')
at filterTemplate (angular-modules.60e5f3e3b5307d61d538d0d0c914694c.js:4023:20)
at Yt (lodash.min.js:10:252)
at Function.Ce (lodash.min.js:38:58)
at angular-modules.60e5f3e3b5307d61d538d0d0c914694c.js:4042:28
at angular.min.js?r=WZDNuen_US:141:454
at m.$digest (angular.min.js?r=WZDNuen_US:153:67)
at angular.min.js?r=WZDNuen_US:156:267
at Yg.completeTask (angular.min.js?r=WZDNuen_US:168:231)
at angular.min.js?r=WZDNuen_US:52:229 'Possibly unhandled rejection: {}'


I tried uninstalling the extension and reinstalling it to start from scratch (which I would rather not have to do) and the editing interface does not come up at all.

Any help in getting Mosaico to work is greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Steve

looks like the template path issue

I figured out there were two different template directories depending on the template and I fixed it. Thanks!

@Pradeep Nayak, I spoke to soon, shoot, I can edit the templates but I cannot start a new mailing.  https://crm.chasethemusic.org/sites/default/files/CiviCRM_Mosaico_Editor_Working.png.  I have tested all my templates and they appear to be editable like the one in the screenshot above.  I just cannot use them for a mailing. The error appears the same as before when trying to create a new mailing. I appreciate any help!

See my comment to the answer.  This has been solved by deleting rows out of civicrm_mosaico_template without metadata.

@Pradeep Nayak was right the issue was still the templates directory.  In my case the Mosaico and Mailing Configuration Changes extension was working.
I just had multiple paths for templates in the database.  You can find this by looking at the metadata column of the civicrm_mosaico_template table.
Follow the directions with the configuration changes module and this becomes a simple fix.

Make sure there are not rows without metadata in civicrm_mosaico_template.  This will cause templates not to display.
